# How can I execute a random command line and reproduce the process?

Tags: python, linux, shell, command-line

There are about 100+ commands written in a file; each line is a command. How can I read these command lines and execute them randomly? And, more importantly, how can I reproduce the process when some problem occurred (maybe use the same `random.seed`)?

Comment: To your second question - yes, use the same `seed`. To the first - what?

Comment: Use a random seed or one specified by some user.

Answer (score 1):

Same rand.seed will give same randomizaton sequance, so yes.

As of first, just read the commands into an array. Then using random numbers between 0 and len(command array) - 1 execute that command and delete it from the array.

```
cmds = file_handle.readlines()
random.seed(seed_number)
while (cmds):
   item = 0
   if (len(cmds) > 0):
       item = random.randrange(len(cmds) - 1)
   exec(cmds[item])   # This is terribly dangerous stuff, and ugly
   cmds.remove(cmds[item])
```

Comment: Why not just `random.shuffle(cmds)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that is a good way as well. Then you could perhaps use the map function or the array notion `[do_something for for something in a_array]` . I just tend to like randomizing over integers for some reason